# Equations of tangents and normals

Tags: calculus

A tangent is drawn on the graph y = k/x at the point where x=a (a>0). The tangent intersects the y-axis at P and the x-axis at Q. If O is the origin, show that the area of the triangle OPQ is independent of a.

Comment: Hi, please show some effort? what have you tried?

Comment: Well, the reason I asked this on StackExchange was because I don't know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: You have mentioned that you don't how to begin. It seems that you are new to MSE. It is highly recommended to show your work. I will give you some hints:
1. If $x=a$ what is the corresponding $y$ value according to the equation?
2. The slope of the tangent equals the derivative at $x=a$.
3. Now you have a point and a slope, hence you can find the tangent equation.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To find the area of the triangle, we must first find the equation of the tangent line:

First, we find the slope of our tangent line:

$$y' = -\frac{k}{x^2}$$
$$y'(a) = -\frac{k}{a^2}$$

We also know that passes through the point $(a, \frac{k}{a})$.

Therefore, we can use the point-slope form to find the equation of the line:

$$y - \frac{k}{a} = -\frac{k}{a^2}\left(x - a\right)$$

$$y = -\frac{k}{a^2}x + \frac{2k}{a}$$

Since we have a triangle with a point on the origin, we can simply use the formula $A = \frac{1}{2}bh$ and find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts:

The $x$ -intercept is $(2a, 0)$.

The $y$ -intercept is $(0, \frac{2k}{a})$.

Thus, finding the area, we get:

$$A = \frac{1}{2}*2a*\frac{2k}{a} = 2k$$

And we have finally proved the area is independent of $a$.

Comment: it should be $2k$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thanks for correcting my mistake

Answer (score 0):

the equation of the tangent line is given by $y=\frac{2k}{a}-\frac{kx}{a^2}$ the point $P$ has the coordinates $P(0;\frac{2k}{a})$ and $Q(2a;0)$ thus the area of the triangle $OPQ$ is given by $A=2k>0$ by simplification